# Can not install com_cjlib (CoreJoomla Framework Library)

Tags: component, extensions

I have a local XAMPP Joomla! website that I am trying to add CjBlog to, but it needs CoreJoomla Framework Library which keeps giving me "Error Please enter a package folder. Unable to find install package". Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: The Joomla framework is shipped with the Joomla CMS. If your extension is not installing correctly, I suggest you contact the developer